# How to convert the save data to JTable in other class

Tags: java

I would like to output the information which was inserted in my software class which is :

```
public class SoftwareProducts extends JPanel implements ActionListener  
JTextField ramtf;
JTextField processortf;
JTextField productIDtf;
JTextField productNametf;
JTextField productYeartf;
JTextField productPublishHousetf;

//JTextField ram;
JButton CompleteOrder;

JLabel Ramlb; 
JLabel processorlb;
JLabel productIDlb;
JLabel productNamelb; 
JLabel productYearlb;
JLabel PublishHouselb;

 JPanel softwarePanel;
 CardLayout c2 = new CardLayout();
 GridBagLayout gridBag;
 GridBagConstraints c;

 CompleteOrder completeOrder;
public static void main(String [] args){

    new SoftwareProducts();
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new SoftwareProducts());


    //Jframe f = new JFrame();


  }

 /* public void addComponent(Component comp,
       int gx,int gy,int t,int l,int b,int r)
  {
    c.gridx=gx;
    c.gridy=gy;
    c.insets=new Insets(t,l,b,r);
    gridBag.setConstraints(comp,c);
    add(comp);
  } */


 public SoftwareProducts()
{

      //getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);
      //GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
      //GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    setSize(500,300);
    gridBag = new GridBagLayout();
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    setLayout(gridBag);


    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    c.gridy = 0;

    Ramlb = new JLabel("Ram:");
    add(Ramlb, c);

    ramtf = new JTextField(10);
    add(ramtf, c);

    c.gridy = 1; 

    processorlb = new JLabel("Process:");
    add(processorlb, c);

    processortf = new JTextField(10);
    add(processortf, c);

     c.gridy = 2; 

    productIDlb = new JLabel("Product ID:");
    add(productIDlb, c);

    productIDtf = new JTextField(10);
    add(productIDtf, c);

    c.gridy = 3; 

    productNamelb = new JLabel("Product Name:");
    add(productNamelb, c);

    productNametf = new JTextField(10);
    add(productNametf, c);

    c.gridy = 4;

    productYearlb = new JLabel("Product Year:");
    add(productYearlb, c);

    productYeartf = new JTextField(10);
    add(productYeartf, c);

    c.gridy = 5;

    PublishHouselb = new JLabel("Publish House:");
    add(PublishHouselb, c);

    productPublishHousetf = new JTextField(10);
    add(productPublishHousetf, c);

    /*
    Ramlb = new JLabel("Ram:");
    processorlb = new JLabel("Processor:"); 
    productIDlb = new JLabel("Product ID:");
    productNamelb = new JLabel("Product Name:");
    productYearlb = new JLabel("Product Year:");
    PublishHouselb = new JLabel("Publish House:");
    //ramtf.setEditable(false);
    ramtf = new JTextField(15);
    //add(ramtf);
    processortf = new JTextField(15);
    productIDtf = new JTextField(10);
    productNametf = new JTextField(10);
    productYeartf = new JTextField(10);
    productPublishHousetf = new JTextField(10);


    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    addComponent(ramtf,1,0,0,0,0,0);
    addComponent(Ramlb,0,0,0,0,0,0);
    addComponent(processortf,1,1,0,0,0,0);
    addComponent(processorlb,0,1,0,0,0,0);
    addComponent(productIDtf,1,2,0,0,0,0);
    addComponent(productIDlb,0,2,0,0,0,0);
    addComponent(productNametf,1,3,0,0,0,0);
    addComponent(productNamelb,0,3,0,0,0,0);
    addComponent(productYeartf,1,4,0,0,0,0);
    addComponent(productYearlb,0,4,0,0,0,0);
    addComponent(productPublishHousetf,1,5,0,0,0,0);
    addComponent(PublishHouselb,0,5,0,0,0,0);*/
    //addComponent(CompleteOrder,1,6,0,0,0,0);

    //ramtf.addActionListener(this);

       //ramtf.setBounds(0,0,130,150);

    //add(processorlb);







    //processortf = new JTextField(15);
    //processortf.addActionListener(this);

    //add(processortf);

    //add(productIDlb);



    //productIDtf.addActionListener(this);



    //add(productIDtf);

    //add(productNamelb);

    //add(productNamelb);

    //productNametf.addActionListener(this);

   // add(productNametf);

    //add(productYearlb);

    //productYeartf.addActionListener(this);

   // add(productYeartf);

    //add(PublishHouselb);



    //productPublishHousetf.addActionListener(this);

    //add(productPublishHousetf);



    CompleteOrder = new JButton("CompleteOrder");
    CompleteOrder.setSize(35,40);
    //CompleteOrder.setLocation(200,140);
    CompleteOrder.addActionListener(this);
    add(CompleteOrder); 





   //softwarePanel = new JPanel();
    //softwarePanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));



    //softwarePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    //softwarePanel.add(Ramlb);


      //softwarePanel = setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    //softwarePanel.setLayout(c2);



      completeOrder = new CompleteOrder();
      //softwarePanel.add(new JPanel(),"empty");
      //softwarePanel.add(completeOrder,"completeOrder");




      //this.add(softwarePanel);

       //submit = new Press();
       //softwarePanel.add(submit,"submit");

       //add(softwarePanel);


      this.setVisible(true);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

{


    if(e.getSource() == CompleteOrder)
    {

        //ramtf.removeAllElements();;

        //c2.show(softwarePanel,"completeOrder");



        float ram = Float.parseFloat(ramtf.getText());

        float processor = Float.parseFloat(processortf.getText());

        int productID = Integer.parseInt(productIDtf.getText());

        String productName = productNametf.getText();

       int productYear = Integer.parseInt(productYeartf.getText());

       String productPublishHouse = productPublishHousetf.getText();



       main.softwareList.add(new Software(productID,productName,productYear,productPublishHouse));


       ramtf.setText("");
      //processortf.setText("");


      System.out.println("Saved");

    }
 }
}
```

And show them in other class IN JTABLE that what I was told to put all the information that was entered to and save them in JTable which is my complete Order class which is :

```
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  import java.util.*;
  import java.io.*;
  public class CustomerOrder extends JPanel implements ActionListener 

 {

//JButton asd = new JButton("BUTTON");
//JTextField productID;
//JTextField productName;
//JTextField productCost;
//JTextField productPYear;
//JTextField productPHouse;

JButton showOrder;


DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
JList orderList = new JList(model);






public CustomerOrder()
{

    //super();

   // JLabel toLabel=new JLabel("Product ID: ");
    //JTextField to=new JTextField();


    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    //productID = new JTextField(12);
    //add(productID);

    /*JPanel productPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel productIDLabel = new JLabel("Product ID:");
    JLabel productNameLabel = new JLabel("Product Name:");
    JLabel productCostLabel = new JLabel("Product Cost:");
    JLabel productPublicationYearLabel = new JLabel("Product Publication Year:");
    JLabel productPublicationHouseLabel = new JLabel("Product PublicationHouse:");

    productPanel.add(productIDLabel);
    productPanel.add(productID);
    productPanel.add(productNameLabel);
    productPanel.add(productName);
    productPanel.add(productCostLabel);
    productPanel.add(productCost);
    productPanel.add(productPublicationYearLabel);
    productPanel.add(productPYear);
    productPanel.add(productPublicationHouseLabel);
    productPanel.add(productPHouse);

    */

   // setContentPane(productPanel);


    //add(orderList);




   /* 
    productName = new JTextField(12);
    add(productName);

    productCost = new JTextField(12);
    add(productCost);

    productPYear = new JTextField(12);
    add(productPYear);


    productPHouse = new JTextField(12);
    add(productPHouse);

    */
    showOrder = new JButton("SHOW ORDER");
    showOrder.setSize(25,40);
    showOrder.addActionListener(this);
    add(showOrder); 


   //add(model);

   add(orderList);



}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

{
    if(e.getSource() == showOrder)
    {
         model.removeAllElements();

         int x = 0;


       while (x < main.softwareList.size())
        {
            //./model.addElement(main.softwareList.get(x).getproductYear());
             model.addElement(""+ main.softwareList.get(x).getRam());
             model.addElement(""+ main.softwareList.get(x).getProcessor());
             model.addElement(""+ main.softwareList.get(x).getproductID()); 
             model.addElement(main.softwareList.get(x).getproductName());
             model.addElement(""+ main.softwareList.get(x).getproductYear());
             model.addElement(main.softwareList.get(x).getproductPublishHouse());
            //model.addElement(main.softwareList.get(x).getproductID());


             x++;

          //System.out.println("as");


        }

    }

}
}
```

So I am really looking to solve it 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you want to put CustomOrder's into a JTable?

Comment: Yes I would like to put the customer table in to JTable